# PDPT Pointer Bits

Tags: kernel

I am trying to boot a custom build of Apple’s XNU kernel ([sources](https://github.com/Andromeda-OS/Kernel)). The boot is dying due to an unhandled page fault. I have traced the cause of the crash to the [`BootPDPT`](https://github.com/Andromeda-OS/Kernel/blob/master/osfmk/x86_64/boot_pt.c#L54-L60) symbol. The job of the `BootPDPT` is to point to the page-table entries in the `BootPDT` symbol.

The problem is, as I currently understand the x86 PDPT, the low 16 bits or so are flags, and the address is located in the high 16 bits. (I checked [OSDev](http://wiki.osdev.org/Paging) for my research). Does this mean that I need to shift that address so it will be resolved properly?

I am asking this because the MMU is unable to locate the page table entries. I believe that this is due to the value `0x00102000` (the address of the `BootPDT`) being interpreted as `0x00000102` due to value shifting.

If I do need to shift the address left, how many bits would I shift the value by, and how do I do this in assembler without mangling the flags in the low 16 bits?